# problem installing turtlebot on ros-groovy

Tags: turtlebot, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 and ros-groovy and when I try to install turtlebot package I get the following problem:

```
viki@ROS:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-turtlebot
[sudo] password for viki: 

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-groovy-turtlebot : Depends: ros-groovy-zeroconf-avahi-suite (= 0.2.2-0precise-20131015-2213-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ros-groovy-navigation (= 1.10.3-s1383961963~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ros-groovy-multimaster-experimental (= 0.2.1-s1381889748~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ros-groovy-xacro (= 1.7.4-s1381889842~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ros-groovy-ros-comm (= 1.9.50-0precise-20131016-0131-+0000) but 1.9.39-0precise-20121230-1434-+0000 is to be installed
                        Depends: ros-groovy-turtlebot-create (= 2.0.1-s1381895136~precise) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ros-groovy-kobuki (= 0.3.9-1precise-20131016-0554-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ros-groovy-kobuki-description (= 0.3.2-s1381895153~precise) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Please, Can help me someone to resolve this problem? I don't know what should I do.
thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/105661/problem-installing-turtlebot-on-ros-groovy/) by [Maikel](https://answers.ros.org/users/9266/maikel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like more a Linux/Ubuntu problem to me. One or more dependencies of one or more of the packages you are going to install are causing troubles. You need to locate those dependencies to find out more about the problem you are actually having.

synaptic and aptitude may help here.

Other options are: You recently made changes in the depositories/depository list you are getting the packages from. E.g. package depends on version X.Y, but available is only X.(Y-1). I get that sometimes, when switching my Ubuntu repos to non-default, but faster ones.

Btw, are you running 32bit or 64bit?

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maikel](https://answers.ros.org/users/9266/maikel/) on 2013-12-03**:
sorry by the delay, I was tripping and I didn't had connection. You are right I had a problem with my repository configuration, thank you very much for your help, I fix it and now it work. Thank again.